# Instagram Graph API: me/accounts does not return my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to access my Instagram account via the Instagram Graph API. The documentation says that you need to link your account to the FB page. But when you connect an Instagram account to a page, roles change on this page and my FB account disappears from there and there is no way to return it. Thus, both the explorer and curl request returns an empty array of my pages, and in the page usage history it is written that the Instagram account has claimed ownership of this page.

access_token is fine, I can get the id of my pages until the Instagram account is connected to them. Moreover, in all the guides that I watched, all these actions work correctly (although they are all quite old and the principle of working with pages has already changed in FB, you need to switch to them to work with). What could be the problem, maybe I'm doing something wrong?

I've seen similar topics here. But no one said that the Instagram account is essentially stealing my page from me (although I still have all administrator rights, deletion, etc.)
About returning my account to the Roles tab: there is no working search, and I can't find my account even by email

Answer (score 6):

try to add **business_management**  permission, I had the same problem, and finally, this worked for me

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was struggling with this for hours. Explains why this started appearing after I got more rights!